# Distribution of US after-tax money income by household size

Tags: data-request, cps

I'm looking for the US household distribution of after-tax after-transfers income by household size, at a finer grain than quintiles. CPS has total money income ([after-transfer](https://www.census.gov/cps/data/incdef.html)) in ~$2,500 increments, but  I can't find an after-tax version. Do the full census, BLS, or think tanks estimate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find this information [here](https://ourworldindata.org/incomes-across-the-distribution/). They provide an overview of their results, together with a link to the data and its description. The data is also available through [LIS](http://www.lisdatacenter.org/resources/other-databases/) (second item).

Interestingly, this does not only include the US, but also many other OECD countries, in a homogeneous methodology (great for comparisons). Additionally, this is a longitudinal study of each country. In total, **they have data for 27 developed countries between 1978 and 2013**.

The data is very comprehensive, and it is **at the decile level**. It includes:

- Entire population, decile cut-offs, equivalised household income
- Working age population, decile cut-offs, equivalised household income
- Entire population, decile means, equivalised household income
- Working age population, decile means, equivalised household income
- Entire population, decile cut-offs, per capita household income
- Working age population, decile cut-offs, per capita household income
- Deflator and PPP